# Branch.io deeplink in android opens Play Store even no matter what

Tags: android, branch.io

No matter what, when I click on a link created with branch.io, the user is taken to Google Play :-((

This is the relevant activity in the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.DetailActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|screenSize|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="open"
                android:scheme="foo" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the branch.io dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

From the [Deferred Deep Linking SDK for Android README](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Android-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK):

> **Chrome seems to take me to Google Play all the time. Why?**
>
> Chrome is very picky about opening up the app directly. Chrome
>   utilizes the intent system to try to open up the app, and fails back
>   to the Play Store far too easily. Here are 3 things to verify:
>
> 1. Make sure the package name for the test build matches the package registered in the Branch settings and matches the package in Google
>      play.
> 2. Make sure the URI scheme of the test build matches the Branch settings.
> 3. Verify that you've added the proper host 'open' in the Manifest - see [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-Android-SDK#register-an-activity-for-direct-deep-linking-optional-but-recommended)

I see that you use this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foo.inappbilling) as example. Please check that the package name of your application it is `com.foo.inappbilling`, otherwise the `Branch.io` link will not open your app and will always open the Google Play Store.

I was able to reproduce your issue and I solved by setting the correct package name. If you use Gradle you can do it directly from `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foo.inappbilling"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
```

Comment: One thing to add, "Support existing routing based on this URI scheme is selected". If that's the case, foo:// is going to open + whatever is specified for the key $deeplink_path. So, $deeplink path will need bar!

Comment: @Mattia Maestrini: Must we set `host` to `open`, or we can use any keyword?

Answer (score 1):

have you checked (always try to open app) in your dashboard inside link settings above the scheme definition? 
Also make sure the scheme you set in the manifest is without "://" refer @inverce answer for more description.

Answer (score 1):

In the dashboard setting/link setting/

select custom URL and enter your package name of your application

Comment: This just doesn't work, and quite rightly, as the package name is not a URL.

Comment: without package name it is not possible to open app from url and this work perfectly in my app